# Dynamic Spill Formula For Reduce Function Mixed With Split

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aUOBVfqS86SRxaXmGs7zKCLl8PFXQqmkI_3lToQ5mU4/edit?usp=sharing) is probably easier to understand than my writing but here's the issue: I have a sheet that I'm trying to create a spill formula that sums an array of numbers up in each line.

- Columns `B:D` is my existing data that's being evaluated
- If values exist in Column `D` (which is not always the case), split values (defined by `,` ) and lookup each one's most recent entry (column `B`) and sum its value from column `C` with other members in same cell.

I can accomplish this using the [Reduce](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/reduce-function/#:%7E:text=This%20can%20also%20operate%20as%20an%20array%20function%20to%20clean%20up%20an%20entire%20array%20of%20names%20with%20a%20single%20formula%3A) formula shown in my sample data in blue column `F`, and dragging the formula to the latest entry, however it will not spill down dynamically.

```
=iferror(REDUCE(0,SPLIT(D2,",",false),lambda(total,value,xlookup(value,B:B,C:C,"",0,-1)+total)),0)
```

I can get the `C` values to spill down dynamically (as shown in green columns in sample) as numeric values, but I can't figure out how to sum them.

```
=Filter(iferror(XLOOKUP(SPLIT(D2:D,", ",false),B:B,C:C,"",0,-1),0),A2:A>0)
```

I would have expected something like either of these to work, but both generate a `#N/A`

```
=Filter(iferror(REDUCE(0,SPLIT(D2:D,", ",false),
 lambda(total,value,xlookup(value,B:B,C:C,"",0,-1)+total)),0),A2:A>0)

=Filter(sum(iferror(XLOOKUP(SPLIT(D2:D,", ",false),B:B,C:C,"",0,-1),0)),A2:A>0)
```

I've also tried these as named functions with only the spilled variables as input, but same result.

I know the reduce function can perform a spilled range, [as shown here on Ben Collins' site](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/reduce-function/#:%7E:text=This%20can%20also%20operate%20as%20an%20array%20function%20to%20clean%20up%20an%20entire%20array%20of%20names%20with%20a%20single%20formula%3A), however I can't figure out how to get it to do so with my dataset. It's occurred to me that because I'm generating a horizontal array, a verticle array may not be possible?

Any helpful answers will be upvoted if not accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
=byrow(index(map(iferror(split(D2:index(D:D,match(2,1/(D:D<>""))),", ",0,1)),lambda(z,xlookup(z,B:B,C:C,)))),lambda(y,sum(y)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To have your formula spill down you can use MAP or BYROW:

Your formula:

`=iferror(REDUCE(0,SPLIT(D2,", ",false),lambda(total,value,xlookup(value,B:B,C:C,"",0,-1)+total)),0)`

With MAP:

`=MAP(D2:D7,LAMBDA(ζ,iferror(REDUCE(0,SPLIT(ζ,", ",false),lambda(total,value,xlookup(value,B:B,C:C,"",0,-1)+total)),0)))`

---

Here's another solution using FILTER:

`=MAP(D2:INDEX(D:D,MAX(ROW(D:D)*(D:D<>""))),LAMBDA(ζ,IFNA(SUM(FILTER(C:C,COUNTIF(SPLIT(ζ,", ",),B:B))),0)))`

Comment: Thanks. Freak Rock Show beat you the ✅ it, but I upvoted ayour answer.